# How would I be able to display the amount of times a number appeared

Tags: java

I am new to coding so far I really enjoy it. But I have been having difficulties with a program. Any help on the following code will get me closer to a solution. I apologize if my code is bad. X is what I'm trying to solve I'm not even sure what to try. Thank you

```
public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("How many sides do your die have");
       int amountOfSides = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("How many times to roll, enter an amount");
       int rollAmount = input.nextInt();
       rolledDie(rollAmount, amountOfSides);
    }

    public static void rolledDie(int rollAmount, int amountOfSides) {        
       int[] dieRoll = new Random().ints(rollAmount,1,amountOfSides).toArray(); 
       System.out.println("Number of rolls: "+rollAmount+ ""
            + "\n"+"Number of sides in your die: "+amountOfSides);
       System.out.println("\n"+"You rolled: "+ java.util.Arrays.toString(dieRoll));
       for (int i = 1; i <= rollAmount; i++) {   
          System.out.println("\n"+"Side: "+i+" Appeared: "+ X + " time(s)");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with this line:

```
int[] dieRoll = new Random().ints(rollAmount,1,amountOfSides).toArray();
```

If you look at the documentation for [Random.ints()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) you'll see that the 2nd in the range argument is exclusive - i.e. you won't get these values. So, you need to add one:

```
int[] dieRoll = new Random().ints(rollAmount,1,amountOfSides+1).toArray();
```

As to the number of times each value appears, create an array to hold the counts, and go through the `dieRoll` incrementing the value at the appropriate index each time:

```
int[] count = new int[amountOfSides];
for (int i = 0; i < rollAmount; i++) {   
    count[dieRoll[i]-1] += 1;
}
```

Note that you need to decrement the roll value by one since Java arrays are zero-indexed.

To print out the number of times each value appears you want to iterate over `count`, not `dieRoll`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfSides; i++) {   
   System.out.println("\n"+"Side: "+i+" Appeared: "+ count[i-1] + " time(s)");
}
```

The complete method is then:

```
  public static void rolledDie(int rollAmount, int amountOfSides) {
    int[] dieRoll = new Random().ints(rollAmount,1,amountOfSides+1).toArray(); 
    System.out.println("Number of rolls: "+rollAmount+ ""
         + "\n"+"Number of sides in your die: "+amountOfSides);
    System.out.println("\n"+"You rolled: "+ java.util.Arrays.toString(dieRoll));

    int[] count = new int[amountOfSides];
    for (int i = 0; i < rollAmount; i++) {   
        count[dieRoll[i]-1] += 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfSides; i++) {   
       System.out.println("\n"+"Side: "+i+" Appeared: "+ count[i-1] + " time(s)");
    }
  }
```

For `rolledDie(10, 6)` you get:

```
Number of rolls: 10
Number of sides in your die: 6

You rolled: [2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 3]

Side: 1 Appeared: 3 time(s)

Side: 2 Appeared: 3 time(s)

Side: 3 Appeared: 2 time(s)

Side: 4 Appeared: 1 time(s)

Side: 5 Appeared: 0 time(s)

Side: 6 Appeared: 1 time(s)
```